# JSPException when managing user roles in WSO2 API Manager

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager

We are using WSO2 API manager version 1.10.0. We are getting errors on the WSO2 API manager console when trying to view user roles or modify user roles. I am getting this error when I am trying to view roles assigned to existing users, or when I am trying to assign new roles to existing users.

**Errors seen are:**

- JSPException while including path '/role/view-users.jsp'
- JSPException while including path '/user/edit-user-roles.jsp'
- JSPException while including path '/user/view-roles.jsp'

etc..

```html
TID: [-1234] [] [2016-11-22 17:42:23,596]  INFO {org.wso2.carbon.core.internal.StartupFinalizerServiceComponent} -  WSO2 Carbon started in 50 sec {org.wso2.carbon.core.internal.StartupFinalizerServiceComponent}
TID: [-1234] [] [2016-11-22 17:42:23,877]  INFO {org.wso2.carbon.ui.internal.CarbonUIServiceComponent} -  Mgt Console URL  : https://<host-ip-hidden>:9443/carbon/ {org.wso2.carbon.ui.internal.CarbonUIServiceComponent}
TID: [-1234] [] [2016-11-22 17:42:23,877]  INFO {org.wso2.carbon.ui.internal.CarbonUIServiceComponent} -  API Publisher Default Context : http://<host-ip-hidden>:9763/publisher {org.wso2.carbon.ui.internal.CarbonUIServiceComponent}
TID: [-1234] [] [2016-11-22 17:42:23,877]  INFO {org.wso2.carbon.ui.internal.CarbonUIServiceComponent} -  API Store Default Context : http://<host-ip-hidden>:9763/store {org.wso2.carbon.ui.internal.CarbonUIServiceComponent}
TID: [-1] [] [2016-11-22 17:42:46,586]  WARN {org.apache.synapse.transport.http.access.AccessConfiguration} -  Error loading properties from file: access-log.properties {org.apache.synapse.transport.http.access.AccessConfiguration}
TID: [-1234] [] [2016-11-22 17:42:47,366]  INFO {org.wso2.carbon.core.services.util.CarbonAuthenticationUtil} -  'admin@carbon.super [-1234]' logged in at [2016-11-22 17:42:47,351-0800] from IP address  {org.wso2.carbon.core.services.util.CarbonAuthenticationUtil}
TID: [-1234] [] [2016-11-22 17:42:47,491]  INFO {org.wso2.carbon.identity.oauth2.dao.TokenMgtDAO} -  Thread pool size for session persistent consumer : 100 {org.wso2.carbon.identity.oauth2.dao.TokenMgtDAO}
TID: [-1234] [] [2016-11-22 17:42:47,726]  INFO {org.apache.synapse.core.axis2.TimeoutHandler} -  This engine will expire all callbacks after : 120 seconds, irrespective of the timeout action, after the specified or optional timeout {org.apache.synapse.core.axis2.TimeoutHandler}
TID: [-1234] [] [2016-11-22 17:42:49,686]  INFO {org.wso2.carbon.identity.oauth.config.OAuthServerConfiguration} -  The default OAuth token issuer will be used. No custom token generator is set. {org.wso2.carbon.identity.oauth.config.OAuthServerConfiguration}
TID: [-1234] [] [2016-11-22 17:43:07,013]  INFO {org.wso2.carbon.core.services.util.CarbonAuthenticationUtil} -  'admin@carbon.super [-1234]' logged in at [2016-11-22 17:43:07,012-0800] {org.wso2.carbon.core.services.util.CarbonAuthenticationUtil}
TID: [-1234] [] [2016-11-22 17:45:51,655] ERROR {org.apache.tiles.jsp.context.JspTilesRequestContext} -  JSPException while including path '/user/edit-user-roles.jsp'.  {org.apache.tiles.jsp.context.JspTilesRequestContext}
javax.servlet.jsp.JspException: ServletException while including page.
 at org.apache.tiles.jsp.context.JspUtil.doInclude(JspUtil.java:102)
 at org.apache.tiles.jsp.context.JspTilesRequestContext.include(JspTilesRequestContext.java:88)
 at org.apache.tiles.jsp.context.JspTilesRequestContext.dispatch(JspTilesRequestContext.java:82)
 at org.apache.tiles.impl.BasicTilesContainer.render(BasicTilesContainer.java:465)
 at org.apache.tiles.jsp.taglib.InsertAttributeTag.render(InsertAttributeTag.java:140)
 at org.apache.tiles.jsp.taglib.InsertAttributeTag.render(InsertAttributeTag.java:117)
 at org.apache.tiles.jsp.taglib.RenderTagSupport.execute(RenderTagSupport.java:171)
 at org.apache.tiles.jsp.taglib.RoleSecurityTagSupport.doEndTag(RoleSecurityTagSupport.java:75)
 at org.apache.tiles.jsp.taglib.ContainerTagSupport.doEndTag(ContainerTagSupport.java:80)
 at org.apache.jsp.admin.layout.template_jsp._jspx_meth_tiles_005finsertAttribute_005f7(template_jsp.java:640)
 at org.apache.jsp.admin.layout.template_jsp._jspService(template_jsp.java:356)
 at org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
 at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:727)
 at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:432)
 at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:395)
 at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:339)
 at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:727)
 at org.wso2.carbon.ui.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:155)
 at org.wso2.carbon.ui.TilesJspServlet.service(TilesJspServlet.java:80)
 ...
 at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:421)
 at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1074)
 at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:611)
 at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1739)
 at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1698)
 at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
 at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
 at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
 at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: org.apache.jasper.JasperException: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.jsp.user.edit_002duser_002droles_jsp
 at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.getServlet(JspServletWrapper.java:177)
 at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:369)
 at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:395)
 at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:339)
 at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:727)
 at org.wso2.carbon.ui.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:155)
 ...
 at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doInclude(ApplicationDispatcher.java:604)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.include(ApplicationDispatcher.java:543)
 at org.eclipse.equinox.http.servlet.internal.RequestDispatcherAdaptor.include(RequestDispatcherAdaptor.java:37)
 at org.eclipse.equinox.http.helper.ContextPathServletAdaptor$RequestDispatcherAdaptor.include(ContextPathServletAdaptor.java:369)
 at org.apache.jasper.runtime.JspRuntimeLibrary.include(JspRuntimeLibrary.java:954)
 at org.apache.jasper.runtime.PageContextImpl.include(PageContextImpl.java:656)
 at org.apache.tiles.jsp.context.JspUtil.doInclude(JspUtil.java:98)
 ... 86 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.jsp.user.edit_002duser_002droles_jsp
 at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
 at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
 at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
 at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
 at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JasperLoader.loadClass(JasperLoader.java:132)
 at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JasperLoader.loadClass(JasperLoader.java:63)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.DefaultInstanceManager.newInstance(DefaultInstanceManager.java:121)
 at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.getServlet(JspServletWrapper.java:172)
 ... 109 more
TID: [-1234] [] [2016-11-22 17:45:51,662] ERROR {org.apache.tiles.jsp.taglib.RoleSecurityTagSupport} -  IO Error executing tag: JSPException while including path '/user/edit-user-roles.jsp'. ServletException while including page. {org.apache.tiles.jsp.taglib.RoleSecurityTagSupport}
java.io.IOException: JSPException while including path '/user/edit-user-roles.jsp'. ServletException while including page.
 at org.apache.tiles.jsp.context.JspTilesRequestContext.include(JspTilesRequestContext.java:91)
 at org.apache.tiles.jsp.context.JspTilesRequestContext.dispatch(JspTilesRequestContext.java:82)
 at org.apache.tiles.impl.BasicTilesContainer.render(BasicTilesContainer.java:465)
 at org.apache.tiles.jsp.taglib.InsertAttributeTag.render(InsertAttributeTag.java:140)
 at org.apache.tiles.jsp.taglib.InsertAttributeTag.render(InsertAttributeTag.java:117)
 at org.apache.tiles.jsp.taglib.RenderTagSupport.execute(RenderTagSupport.java:171)
 at org.apache.tiles.jsp.taglib.RoleSecurityTagSupport.doEndTag(RoleSecurityTagSupport.java:75)
 at org.apache.tiles.jsp.taglib.ContainerTagSupport.doEndTag(ContainerTagSupport.java:80)
 at org.apache.jsp.admin.layout.template_jsp._jspx_meth_tiles_005finsertAttribute_005f7(template_jsp.java:640)
 at org.apache.jsp.admin.layout.template_jsp._jspService(template_jsp.java:356)
 at org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
 at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:727)
 ...
 at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1074)
 at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:611)
 at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1739)
 at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1698)
 at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
 at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
 at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
 at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
TID: [-1234] [] [2016-11-22 17:45:51,664] ERROR {org.apache.tiles.jsp.taglib.RenderTagSupport} -  Error during rendering {org.apache.tiles.jsp.taglib.RenderTagSupport}
javax.servlet.jsp.JspException: IO Error executing tag: JSPException while including path '/user/edit-user-roles.jsp'. ServletException while including page.
 at org.apache.tiles.jsp.taglib.RoleSecurityTagSupport.doEndTag(RoleSecurityTagSupport.java:84)
 at org.apache.tiles.jsp.taglib.ContainerTagSupport.doEndTag(ContainerTagSupport.java:80)
 at org.apache.jsp.admin.layout.template_jsp._jspx_meth_tiles_005finsertAttribute_005f7(template_jsp.java:640)
 at org.apache.jsp.admin.layout.template_jsp._jspService(template_jsp.java:356)
 at org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
 at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:727)
 at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:432)
 at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:395)
 at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:339)
 ...
 at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:950)
 at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.CarbonContextCreatorValve.invoke(CarbonContextCreatorValve.java:57)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:116)
 at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:421)
 at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1074)
 at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:611)
 at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1739)
 at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1698)
 at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
 at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
 at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
 at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: JSPException while including path '/user/edit-user-roles.jsp'. ServletException while including page.
 at org.apache.tiles.jsp.context.JspTilesRequestContext.include(JspTilesRequestContext.java:91)
 at org.apache.tiles.jsp.context.JspTilesRequestContext.dispatch(JspTilesRequestContext.java:82)
 at org.apache.tiles.impl.BasicTilesContainer.render(BasicTilesContainer.java:465)
 at org.apache.tiles.jsp.taglib.InsertAttributeTag.render(InsertAttributeTag.java:140)
 at org.apache.tiles.jsp.taglib.InsertAttributeTag.render(InsertAttributeTag.java:117)
 at org.apache.tiles.jsp.taglib.RenderTagSupport.execute(RenderTagSupport.java:171)
 at org.apache.tiles.jsp.taglib.RoleSecurityTagSupport.doEndTag(RoleSecurityTagSupport.java:75)
 ... 79 more
```

Comment: What is your JDK?

Comment: @bhathiya Java version is 1.7.0_79